# Vue TranslateResult.ToString() shows IDE Error "Method expression is not of Function type"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm

In my Vue.js project I use the "vue-i18n" library for my translation.

When I use the following code, my PhpStorm IDE underlines the `toString()` and shows an error:

```
this.$t("my.translation.key").toString();
```

> Method expression is not of Function type

Everything works fine, but I get the unnecessary IDE error.

Comment: can't reproduce with similar code; please share a sample project (via support ticket, for example) the issue can be repeated with

Comment: Maybe I should add, that I use Vue 2 in my project. As far as I read on the world wide web, the handling of the TranslateResult was improved in Vue 3.

Comment: I've tested this in Vue 2 project with vue-i18n@8.x...

Comment: Hmm, I cannot provide a Sample Project, because the problem occurs at my company and the problem has not the urgency for me to invest such a time into it.
I maybe thought that there might be a "general" solution

Comment: refer from [vue i18n issue]('https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/410#issuecomment-538465940'),   please check the code; replace `t` with `tc`.